# Azure rest API's for editing various build pipeline parameters like Tasks, Variables, triggers, options and retention

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rest-api, build-pipeline

- how to edit various build pipeline parameters  Tasks, Variables,
  triggers, options and retention using Azure rest api's.
- How can we    create Tasks, Variables, triggers, options for existing
  pipeline    using Azure rest API's

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Any specific  information about editing build parameters